# ssis Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: excel, vb.net, ssis, vb.net-2010, ssis-2012

The ssis controlflow consists of a script task which trying to open a n excel file and save it as txt file using workbookopen method and saveas methode.
It shows an error while runing the pkg

```
The file path is of the format \\11.111.111.1\folder1\folder2\file.xlsx


 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

The script being used is

```
Public Sub Main()



        Dim WScript As Object                                    '''= Nothing   '' with out nothing it was showing an error
        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Object



        Dim varoroviderFileLocation_script As String
        Dim varFileName_script As String
        Dim FullPath_script As String

        Dim v_Reversestring As String
        Dim v_ReplaceString As String




        varoroviderFileLocation_script = Dts.Variables("User::varoroviderFileLocation").Value.ToString()
        varFileName_script = Dts.Variables("User::varFileName").Value.ToString()
        FullPath_script = Dts.Variables("User::varoroviderFileLocation").Value.ToString() + "\" + Dts.Variables("User::varFileName").Value.ToString()

        MessageBox.Show(varoroviderFileLocation_script)
        MessageBox.Show(varFileName_script)
        MessageBox.Show(FullPath_script)


        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FullPath_script)

        MessageBox.Show("FullPath_script " + FullPath_script)




        v_Reversestring = StrReverse(FullPath_script)
        v_Reversestring = v_Reversestring.Substring(5, Len(v_Reversestring) - 5)
        MessageBox.Show(v_Reversestring)
        v_Reversestring = StrReverse(v_Reversestring)



        v_ReplaceString = v_Reversestring + ".txt"

        MessageBox.Show("v_ReplaceString  " + v_ReplaceString)

        oBook.SaveAs(v_ReplaceString, -4158)




        oBook.Close(False)
        oExcel.Quit()
        WScript.Echo("Done")


        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you paste the actual (relevant part of the) code of the script component in the question?

Comment: Also: default pitfalls when accessing Excel files: is the file open in another process? You should check the Task Monitor to see if there are lingering instances of EXCEL used by SYSTEM. And does the account you use to run this package have R/W access to the file's location?

Comment: Can you step through the code with a debugger and tell us at which line the error is raised?

Comment: is it inporper assignemnt of string and object variables !

Comment: it is failing in  oBook.SaveAs(v_ReplaceString, -4158) this is the save as .txt step

Comment: And the Messagebox on the line above shows the correct name? Is there already a file with the same name?

Comment: yes msgbox above is showing corr name

Comment: also,it is working good if i replace the ip address with assigned local drive name .That is instead of \\11.111.111.1\folder1\folder2\file.xlsx ,if i use \\Z\folder1\folder2\file.xlsx then it is working.But now the error changed.The excel file has returned with a ~$FileName.xlsx

Comment: The '~filename.xlsx' you see means the original 'filename.xlsx' is still opened, it's a kind of locking mechanism of Excel. Running the package while '~filename.xlsx' exists might result in an 'File is in use by another process'-error.

Comment: That means the last command oBook.Close(False) ned to change to oBook.Close(true)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when working with Office, this error is due to the 64bit runtime.  In project properties under configuration you should have this set to false.  Other times I see this error are when a referenced DLL is not in the GAC or a variable being referenced is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: 64 run time is false .Still shows an error .It shows the file name as ~$File.xlsx, in the debugging